# how to build Defi app from A to Z

Tags: solidity, blockchain, java, defi

I'm a java developer and a newbie with blockchain. I want to build a simple Defi app with a simple smart contract. please tell me know steps by steps to do that?

1. how to setup environment?
2. which the best IDE should be used to write code?
3. which framework should be used? how to compile and deploy?
   I want to use java to build this app, but Java is not supported to write smart contract, so need to combine Java and solidity. but I don't know how to combine them.

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: very easy to do if you think of a contract as another Java class which is called via RPC

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that using just Java and Solidity will get you very far (at least as a beginner). Solidity "back end"/smart contracts and javascript front end using web3.js is the probably the place to start. I recommend the following:

- This guys videos seem like a pretty good all round introduction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3681ZYbDSSk
- Interactive solidity tutorial https://cryptozombies.io
- The tutorial on compiling and testing with truffle and ganache will help you deploy something fast https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3681ZYbDSSk
- Mastering Ethereum is pretty much the definitive texbook on the Ethereum blockchain and is available free on github https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook

Comment: thank for your response. it is very useful for me. your scenario is reasonable, As my understanding Java/Javascript is the most popular programming language is used in blockchain (such as IOTA cryptocurrency, it's built on Java, it means they used java to build at backend in this case) https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-most-popular-programming-languages-used-in-blockchain-development-5133a0a207dc/

Answer (score 0):

For java there's the [web3j](http://web3j.io/).

> Web3j is a highly modular, reactive, type safe Java and Android library for working with Smart Contracts and integrating with clients (nodes) on the Ethereum network: